# How to unblock a pthread from ANY ONE from a list of pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Is there a way in C for any pthread (from a number of previously specified pthreads) to be able to unblock a blocked pthread?

i.e. thread 1 is blocked and it waits for ONE OF threads 2/3/4 to unblock it.

I know about barriers and conditional wait/signal, but they don't seem to allow this.

I was thinking, if there is there a way to block a pthread from another pthread using it's ID, then this could be a solution... but I'm not sure how this can be done either.

Any ideas how I can solve this? thanks :)

Comment: `pthread_cond_signal` or `sem_post`

Comment: with pthread_cond_signal thread 1 would need to wait on a specific thread not any.... and with a semaphore, threads 2 and 3 (for example) could unblock each other without thread 1 ever blocking. I need that thread 1 and one of {2,3,4} block then unblock together, thanks

Comment: How did you block the thread?

Comment: @Gabyazz No, you don't wait on a thread with condition variables, you wait on a condition, you can wait for any of several threads to signal the condition and unblock your thread. Your comment here is the opposite of your question though, in the comment you're mentioning unblocking several threads, while in the question you only mention you want to unblock 1 thread - so please state without any ambiguity what you want your program to do.

Comment: sorry for any misunderstandings... thread 1 checks if threads 2,3 or 4 are in a particular state, if they are not then thread 1 will block and wait for any ONE of those three to unblock it (once that ONE arrives to the required state)... Similarly, if any of threads 2,3,4 arrive to the required state before thread 1, then they will block and wait for thread 1 to unblock them one by one.

Comment: Now my issue is, if thread 1 is blocked, how can I unblock it from any one of the other threads? If I use a 4-way shared semaphore which unblocks after two threads arrive, then threads 2 and 3 (for example) could unblock each other without thread 1 ever blocking. thanks.

Comment: @Gabyazz You have a condition that thread 1 blocks on. When you want to unblock thread 1, you signal that condition. Any thread can signal that condition.